# SQL Incorrect Syntax near

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an error "Incorrect syntax near 'Veh2X', what would the right syntax be for updating multiple columns?

```
string vehicle2Query = "UPDATE [carOwners] SET Vehicle2='" + v2 + "' Veh2X='" + vPosX + "' Veh2Y='" + vPosY + "' Veh2Z='" + vPosZ + "' Veh2XRot='" + vRotX + "'Veh2YRot='" + vRotY + "' Veh2ZRot='" + vRotZ + "' WHERE PlayerName='" + checkPlayerName + "'";
```

Comment: Don't munge query strings by stuffing values in them.  Learn to use parameters for constructing queries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as being a simple typo error.

Comment: I would delete it my self, but I can't, feel free to flag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need commas after each column you set.

```
update your_table 
set a = 1, b = 2, c = 'X'
where ...
```

And you should really look into *Prepared Statements* to avoid such a mess in patching thinks together. And it is a lot more secure too.